# Issue getting past an html form with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Url I am trying to scrape: https://www.uvic.ca/BAN1P/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched

There are 3 pages total, first page to select the **term**, second page to select a **subject**, and the page with the actual **course information**.

The issue I am running into is that once **subject()** calls the **courses()** callback the html in the response.body that is written to the file is the html of the subject page instead of the courses page. How can I tell I am sending the correct form data so that I receive the correct response?

```
# term():
#   Selects the school term to use. Clicks submit

def term(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
    response,
    formxpath="/html/body/div[3]/form",
    formdata={
        "p_term" : "201705" },
    clickdata = { "type": "submit" },
    callback=self.subject
    )

# subject():
#   Selects the subject to query. Clicks submit

def subject(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
    response,
    formxpath="/html/body/div[3]/form",
    formdata={
        "sel_subj" : "ART" },
    clickdata = { "type": "submit" },
    callback=self.courses
    )

# courses():
#   Currently just saves all the html on the page.

def courses(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[-1]
    filename = 'uvic-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

**Debug Output**

```
2017-04-02 01:15:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: scrapy4uvic)
2017-04-02 01:15:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapy4uvic.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapy4uvic.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'scrapy4uvic'}
2017-04-02 01:15:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-04-02 01:15:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-04-02 01:15:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-04-02 01:15:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-04-02 01:15:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-04-02 01:15:28 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-04-02 01:15:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-04-02 01:15:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.uvic.ca/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-04-02 01:15:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.uvic.ca/BAN1P/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched> (referer: None)
2017-04-02 01:15:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.uvic.ca/BAN1P/bwckgens.p_proc_term_date> (referer: https://www.uvic.ca/BAN1P/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched)
2017-04-02 01:15:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.uvic.ca/BAN1P/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec> (referer: https://www.uvic.ca/BAN1P/bwckgens.p_proc_term_date)
2017-04-02 01:15:30 [uvic] DEBUG: Saved file uvic-bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec.html
2017-04-02 01:15:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-04-02 01:15:30 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2335,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 105499,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 2, 8, 15, 30, 103536),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 2, 8, 15, 28, 987034)}
2017-04-02 01:15:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are missing some form data in `subject()`.

I managed to get it working with:

```
formdata={
    "sel_subj": ["dummy", "ART"],
}
```

How I went about debugging it.
First you don't have to save to file, you can `inspect_response` during crawl:

```
def courses(self, response):
    from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
    inspect_response(response, self)
```

This will open up a shell with `response` and `request` object, you can even call `view(response)` to open the html in your browser. It will also use `ipython` or `bpython` shells if those are available, in the example below I use ipython for the convenient formatting.

Second I checked my browser (firefox) what form is it sending when I click the buttons and copied it to shell under variable `bar` and compared it to the request body scrapy was sending:

```
bar = '''term_in=201705&sel_subj=dummy&sel_day=dummy&sel_schd=dummy&sel_insm=dummy&
      sel_camp=dummy&sel_levl=dummy                                                      
      &sel_sess=dummy&sel_instr=dummy&sel_ptrm=dummy&sel_attr=dummy&sel_subj=ART&sel_crse
      =&sel_title=&sel_schd                                                              
      =%25&sel_insm=%25&sel_from_cred=&sel_to_cred=&sel_camp=%25&sel_levl=%25&sel_ptrm=%2
      5&sel_instr=%25&begin_hh                                                           
      =0&begin_mi=0&begin_ap=a&end_hh=0&end_mi=0&end_ap=a'''
# split into arguments
bar = sorted(bar.split('&'))
# do the same with the request body that was sent by scrapy
foo =sorted(request.body.split('&'))
# now join these together and find the differences!
zip(foo, bar)
[('begin_ap=a', 'begin_ap=a'),
 ('begin_hh=0', 'begin_hh\n=0'),
 ('begin_mi=0', 'begin_mi=0'),
 ('end_ap=a', 'end_ap=a'),
 ('end_hh=0', 'end_hh=0'),
 ('end_mi=0', 'end_mi=0'),
 ('sel_attr=dummy', 'sel_attr=dummy'),
 ('sel_camp=%25', 'sel_camp=%25'),
 ('sel_camp=dummy', 'sel_camp=dummy'),
 ('sel_crse=', 'sel_crse='),
 ('sel_day=dummy', 'sel_day=dummy'),
 ('sel_from_cred=', 'sel_from_cred='),
 ('sel_insm=%25', 'sel_insm=%25'),
 ('sel_insm=dummy', 'sel_insm=dummy'),
 ('sel_instr=%25', 'sel_instr=%25'),
 ('sel_instr=dummy', 'sel_instr=dummy'),
 ('sel_levl=%25', 'sel_levl=%25'),
 ('sel_levl=dummy', 'sel_levl=dummy\n'),
 ('sel_ptrm=%25', 'sel_ptrm=%25'),
 ('sel_ptrm=dummy', 'sel_ptrm=dummy'),
 ('sel_schd=%25', 'sel_schd\n=%25'),
 ('sel_schd=dummy', 'sel_schd=dummy'),
 ('sel_sess=dummy', 'sel_sess=dummy'),
 ('sel_subj=ART', 'sel_subj=ART'),
 ('sel_title=', 'sel_subj=dummy'),
 ('sel_to_cred=', 'sel_title='),
 ('term_in=201705', 'sel_to_cred=')]
```

As you can see you were missing "dummy" in `sel_subj` and 'term_in' is there when it shouldn't be but it desn't seem to have an effect :)